# Power Supply for nvidia GTX 970

Tags: power-supply

Bought a GTX 970 yesterday - just arrived, turns out I don't have the connectors required. Tried to bodge it with a 4-pin molex to 8-pin connector, that doesn't fit either.

Any ideas on a cheap-ish (max £60) power supply that could power this GTX? I have no idea about these connectors. I've found [this one](http://www.ebuyer.com/713453-seasonic-s12-ii-620w-80-bronze-certified-psu-jap-caps-12cm-ss-620gb) but I'm not sure it has the connectors I need - all I know is that I need at least one 8-pin and one 6-pin (not sure of the differently terminologies here).

Comment: Could you please explain the reason for the downvotes? I'm open to improving my question but I can't do that if it's blindly downvoted and I'm given no feedback.

Comment: you can find out yourself. here is a calculator where you can see what voltage you need at lease and then you can pick out a psu yourself, i recommend Collermaster and corsair. http://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator

Comment: @Thomcdrom The main issue is connectors rather than voltage. For example, the GTX needs an 8pin and 6pin PCIe connector, which my current PSU doesn't have.

Comment: most of the PSU in the range you are looking at have those connectors. the coolermaster v series have 2x 6+2 pin kables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the [XFX TS 550W 80+ Gold (P1-550G-TS3X)](http://www.cclonline.com/product/179361/P1-550G-TS3X/Power-Supplies/XFX-TS-Series-P1-550G-TS3X-550W-Power-Supply-Unit-Easy-Rail-Plus-with-Full-Wired-Cables/PSU0837/), which currently sells for £55 at CCL online. It is a non modular unit manufactured by Seasonic and rated 80+ Gold. Crucially, there are 2 6+2 pin PCIe connectors and another 2 6 pin connectors, for a total of 4 PCIe connectors; therefore it will not only support your current 970, it will also be capable of handling (subject to capacity limitations) another GTX 970 in SLI, should you choose to upgrade. It also has a 5 year warranty.